Salesforce Outlook Integration Pane shows disabled Log Now button for events
Need a bit of help to understand what exactly may be the issue with Outlook integration.
I cannot seem to log emails/events properly. Specifically, person accounts with unique email addresses are not recognised.
I cannot use Log on Send functionality, because it asks me to add a recipient, even though a recipient is present (see below).
But if I click on "Edit" and choose a customer, then it allows me to use Log on Send. Additionally it populates BCC with some Salesforce long email address.
Second issue is logging events. I seem to not be able to log at all, as button is greyed out.
I am trying to log an all-day event where I am a participant (for example, day-off).
But Log event is greyed out.
Here's a quick run down of the setup

I'm logged in with a user with an email address that matches the Outlook email address.
User is mapped to exchange email.
Publisher layout assigned to user profile.
Default Flexi Pane page is set as default page.
Permissions for events are there.

Any help with the direction to troubleshoot this is greatly appreciated.
Vio

It appears that the reason the "Log Event" button is greyed out is because there are no Lead, Contact, User, or Person Account records matching the email addresses of the event attendees. This is expected behavior, not an issue.
To address this, if the "Log Event" button is greyed out, you should create Lead, Contact, or Person Account records, and then log the event. Note that you can only create these records if the global action to create them is included in a global publisher layout assigned to the profile of the current user.
I hope this helps clarify the situation.
